# Пишу бота для телеграма

Tags: python

Выдает мне данную ошибку
File "D:/Project/untitled/bot.py",line 54
while True:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Process finished with exit code 1 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Тебе даже редактор подсвечивает что не так, поставь там курсор и alt+enter.

Answer (score 1):

У вас внезапно закончился блок try без соответствующей ему конструкции except. Как правильно поправить ваш код не совсем очевидно, судя по дальнейшему коду - там try опять заново начинается внутри цикла. Скорее всего нужно написать забытый except на том же уровне, что и try выше.

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    ...

while true:
    ...
```